# Creating a dynamic URL in node--resource.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I'm trying to create a URL in my node--resource.tpl.php file that contains fields from the resource in question in the URL. The following code is what I've been playing with, but when the user clicks the link it just shows as follows:

```
http://pf.dev/content/specific-resource-feedback?nid=&title=
```

Ie. The nid and title are not being filled out correctly. So here's the code I'm using (incorrectly) to create the URL:

```
    <div class="feedback-link">
    <a href="/content/specific-resource-feedback?nid=
<?php $content['nid']) ?>&title= <?php $content['title']) ?>">
Trouble with this resource? Let us know.</a>
    </div>
```

Any ideas why this might not be working as intended?

Comment: Because $content['nid'] and $content['title'] are empty... Install devel and use dpm($content); to see what's inside $content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is defined for a node.tpl.php file as $title, and the node id can be retrieved with: `<?php print $node->nid; ?>`  therefore, it should read something like this:

```
<div class="feedback-link">
  <a href="/content/specific-resource-feedback?nid=<?php print $node->nid; ?>&title= <?php print $title; ?>">
  Trouble with this resource? Let us know.</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, much obliged!